# Unique Id for rows in sqlite across all devices in android

Tags: android, sqlite

My app stores offline data in sqlite and then sync it to online server on user choice. I need a unique id for each row in the sqlite so that when i sync / update i can manage status and other things for each row.

The Unique id should be unique across all devices using my app. The option i tried **System.currentTimeMillis()** but it seems it can be duplicate across devices. The other options i searched were **UUID** or merging 2 values like **System.currentTimeMillis()** and **Random.nextLong()** to create unique value

What is the best and reliable approach for doing this ?

Comment: Use UUID, that is exactly what it's designed for.

Comment: Thanks, So i will need to use UUID.randomUUID() for each row row in database ?

Comment: Thanks @323go !! This UUID will be unique across all devices using my app ? And one thing i read somewhere but not sure if its correct - that the UUID doesn't work on some devices ??

Comment: Given a correct implementation, a UUID is unique across devices. Just take a look at the [explanation on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier). I have not seen the UUID not working "on some devices." I know one of the folks below claimed it was, but I've never heard of it, nor seen it in practice. It's part of the Java implementation, and I can't imagine a circumstance where it's missing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You were right on with your UUID. UUID means [Universally Unique IDentifier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier), and it's specifically designed for this distributed computing environment you have, with multiple devices generating unique records. As such, it is "practically unique." This means exactly what it says -- in practice, it will be unique across all your devices and across time. Most implementations employ some form of device ID (such as the practically unique MAC address), as well as a time-element and encrypted location information (geo-IP or similar).

In Java/Android, you can use [`UUID.randomUUID().toString()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/UUID.html) to generate unique primary keys for your SQLite database. Once you sync back to the server, those primary keys will practically be unique.

I would recommend against attempting to implement your own UUID scheme (based on AndroidID, MAC address, IMEI, System Time, etc). While you might gain slight storage advantages, the effort in development and troubleshooting, IMHO, is just not worth it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you though about UUID hashcode + System.currentTimeMillis(), hashcode can duplicate but it has 32bit size, so it hardly possible. If you add System.currentTimeMillis() you will minimize chance for sameId.

If you need one record per device, than you can use UUID, but... take into account that UUID can be sometimes null, and also you need to add additional permissions to get it. In this case most reliable will be: System.currentTimeMillis() + Random.nextLong().

It depends on records number, if you want to have 10 000 - 100 000 unique records than choose one method above and you will be ok. If you are looking for something much bigger than check UUID, Imei, Sim serial number.

This is a nice androidId, unique for device, but beware, it can be null sometimes, thats why I adviced to use System.currentTimeMillis().
import android.provider.Settings.Secure;

private String android_id = Secure.getString(getContext().getContentResolver(),
                                                        Secure.ANDROID_ID);

Comment: This answer is full of wrong information. a UUID is 128 bits, not 32. A UUID generally contains a time-element, so adding time is redundant. What are these alleged cases where UUID is null, and what "additional permissions" do you need to get it? This is all **quite wrong**.

Comment: I said hashcode of UUID, and hashcode is 32 bit. UUID is theoretically unique for device, it does not change in time. When UUID is null than you have System.currentTimeMillis(). I messed a bit with UUID, i meant androidId. Answer edited.

Comment: If you claim that a UUID.hashCode() "hardly" collides, you would have to explain where you get this information, and at the very least, disclaim that risk. Further, you're reducing a UUID from 128 bits to 32 bits, and then suggest adding bits from `currentTimeMillis()` to mitigate the risk of collisions. So you're going from 128 to 32 and then add 63. And now you edited it to include additional unique bits from IMEI, SIM serial, etc. Why? Why not just keep the full UUID?? It's 128 bits of glorious uniqueness that does all the work for you. The wheel was fine. Don't reinvent it.

Comment: Further, your answer still contains the **entirely incorrect** assertion that you need some mythical permissions to generate a UUID, as well as a this strange claim that a generated UUID "may sometimes be null." Where did you get this? Do you know what a UUID is?

Answer (score -1):

Why not try a combination(even simple append ) of UUID and System.currentTimeMillis()?
That will always be unique(provided UUID is not null)

Comment: UUID contains a time-element, there's no need to add the time into it. UUID alone is enough.